# python webriver timout and try/except

Tags: python, selenium, timeout, try-catch

I’m trying to open a link to an mp3 and then close it. To do this I use driver.get(url). If I use http://www.google.com it works. But when I use the mp3 link it stuck at driver.get(url). So it won’t close.
I have tried to use an timeout for loading, but then it gets another error. And it doesn’t do the rest of the code.

If have read somewhere that you can fix this with try and except, but I don’t know what the error is called, so I don’t know what exception I have to use.

The code i use

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
driver.get('https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/bcc67a9c1772e28a01be2074b8a4c850c8bc4587');
driver.quit()
```

the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
driver.get(' https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/bcc67a9c1772e28a01be2074b8a4c850c8bc4587');
File "C:\.....\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 248, in get
self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "C:\.....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: cannot determine loading status
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.002
(Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

    `driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.`**implicitly_wait**`(10)
    driver.get('https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/bcc67a9c1772e28a01be2074b8a4c850c8bc4587');
    driver.quit()`

For further information:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html